# How does WCF service works?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a question about `wcf` service. I found out that it differs than `windows service` whereby windows service can be found in the task manager under the `services` tab. However, when I try to look for `wcf` service, it doesnt show up for some reason. I read online and many articles are quite confusing for me. Can anyone briefly explain to me where is the `wcf` service hosted at? Local machine or some sort of web server and where do I find it? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on how/where you host it. e.g. When hosted in IIS, it will be running under a process named w3wp.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a windows service is something completely different from a WCF service. The intent of a windows service is to have a process run at the system level - independent from the logged on user (in the background), while the intent of a WCF service is to create an interface for communicating with an application (think in terms of a web server, email server, chat server, etc).

A WCF service needs to be hosted within a process. This is typically either a normal application, IIS, or a **windows service** - depending on the need of the application.

So, you see, it's not possible to answer the question of *where* a WCF service is hosted without looking at each individual WCF service - but it's also probably the wrong question. You shouldn't be equating windows services with WCF services in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend you to see this course:

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services-jump-start-8258?l=qDRiJfKy_7604984382

Answer (score 0):

Windows Service and WCF are quite different, In windows service there is only one thread per service (if you doesn't implement multi threading),
Where as in WCF every time new thread is working while calling WCF.

It depends on you where you want to hosted this service, it may be **IIS** or **Window Services**,

In Windows Service you can hosted it as

> installutil (service.exe)

where service.exe is service name found in release and debug folder. and if you have make **setup** of this service, then it is automatically deploy in your path.